# How can I Sort this MVC Drop-Down list alphabetically but IGNORE brackets?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dynamic dropdown list that I need to sort alphabetically, but the issue is, there is some text within brackets that appears on top.

I was asked to sort the text in brackets alphabetically (in this case, it begins with an "R" -- they want the "[OLD] ROI" to be placed above "ROI - English"), even though it technically sorts correctly.

Can someone please help me with a solution? I cannot find an answer anywhere, and I have honestly never done this. Thank you.

Here is the view:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="consentFormSelect">Consent Form : </label>
        <select id="consentFormSelect" class="form-control" onchange="onConsentFormSelectChange()">
            <option value="">Select An Option</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ConsentForms.OrderBy(m => m.CodeDesc.ToString()).ToList())
            {
                <option value="@item.CodeId">@item.CodeDesc</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot of the UI:

[image: Screenshot of UI dropdown]

Comment: @Austin thank you so much for the comment. Replace did work; they just wanted to keep the bracket while sorting it above the other "Rs". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (not the correct one) is to create a property inside your model:

```
public class ConsentForm
{ 
...
   public string CodeDescParsed 
  {
     get { return CodeDesc.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""); }
  }
...
}
```

Then:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ConsentForms.OrderBy(m => m.CodeDescParsed.ToString()).ToList())
```

There are other ways as well, but they require advanced Linq.

Comment: It did what it needed to do perfectly! Thank you SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the items (to remove the prefix), sort it on the cleaned value and then return the original list of values ordered based on the cleaned value.

```
void Main()
{
    List<string> items = new()
    {
        "[OLD] ROI English Advance Directive(18 +) ",
        "Advance Directive(18 +) (Spanish)",
        "Clinical Supervision Form ",
        "Clinical Supervision Form(Spanish) ",
        "Consent for Telehealth Services-English ",
        "Consent for Telehealth Services-Spanish ",
        "Consent for Treatment and Evaluation ",
        "Consent for Treatment and Evaluation(Spanish) ",
        "Consumer Handbook Acknowledgement ",
        "Contexture ROI English ",
        "Contexture ROI Spanish ",
        "Intake / Annual Consent Packet ",
        "Intake / Annual Consent Packet(Spanish) ",
        "ROI - English ",
        "ROI - Spanish ",
        "SUD Release SUD Release(Spanish)",
    };
    
    var sortedItems = CustomSort(items, "[OLD] ");
}

public List<string> CustomSort(List<string> items, string prefix)
{
    List<(string cleaned, string original)> cleaned = new();
    
    foreach(var i in items)
        cleaned.Add(new(i.Replace(prefix, string.Empty), i));
    var sorted = cleaned.OrderBy(i => i.cleaned).ToList();
    return sorted.Select(i => i.original).ToList();
}
```

sortedItems:

```
Advance Directive(18 +) (Spanish)
Clinical Supervision Form 
Clinical Supervision Form(Spanish) 
Consent for Telehealth Services-English 
Consent for Telehealth Services-Spanish 
Consent for Treatment and Evaluation 
Consent for Treatment and Evaluation(Spanish) 
Consumer Handbook Acknowledgement 
Contexture ROI English 
Contexture ROI Spanish 
Intake / Annual Consent Packet 
Intake / Annual Consent Packet(Spanish) 
ROI - English 
ROI - Spanish 
[OLD] ROI English Advance Directive(18 +) 
SUD Release SUD Release(Spanish)
```